# Remove runnable attribute from a source file in Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4 and have mistakenly set an abstract class to be the default application class..

It's not too much of an issue as I have set the correct one again, which works fine most of the time, but not when I am editing the incorrect one and hit F11 - it attempts to run the project via this incorrect class. Is there any way to remove the "runnable" attribute from this file so that this doesn't happen?

An example of how this looks in the package explorer is below (Application.as is the correct file, AbstractQuickDraggable.as is not):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by following the steps from [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ui_reference_2.html) (under "Setting project application file properties" - relevant part is in italics below):

- In the Flex Navigator view, select a project.
- Right-click (Control-click on Mac OS) to display the context menu and select Properties > Flex Applications (or ActionScript Applications).

You can set the following compiler properties:

- **Select the Runnable Application Files** Selects the list of project files that have been  set as runnable files.
- **Add** Allows you to select project files set as runnable application files (compiled as separate SWF files).
- ***Remove** Removes the selected file from the list of runnable application files.*
- **Set as Default** Sets the selected application files as the default (main) application file in your project.
- Modify the list of application files as needed, and click OK.